# Fuseki Upload Connection Refused

Tags: java, localhost, rdf, jena, fuseki

I am trying to upload an RDF Model to my Jena/Fuseki (runs in docker container).

```
public void sendToJena() {
    DatasetAccessor accessor = DatasetAccessorFactory
            .createHTTP("http://localhost:3030/test/");
    accessor.putModel(model);
}
```

The code above runs insinde an Payara Application Server (also in docker container).

Everytime the method gets executed I recieve connection refused:

```
StandardWrapperValve[Jersey Web Application]: Servlet.service() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Any ideas or thoughts on this? Thanks, Jakob

EDIT:

Already tried to pass the createHTTP() method a custom HTTP client, did not work as well.

Comment: `Connection refused` means exactly what it says.  The remote host/port refused the connection.  In your case, it means you don't have anything listening on port 3030 on your machine.  If Jena is running in a container it probably is not reachable at `localhost` but at its own IP address.

Comment: Your comment led me in the right direction, I used the container´s IP adress and it worked fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to lookup the IP-Address of the Fuseki Docker Container and replace localhost with it.